# How to use certificates with Smack 4.2

Tags: android, ssl, xmpp, smack

I am trying to connect to Blah.im XMPP server, but it requires SSL/TLS certificates for connection. I am using the code below for the connection, but how can I use certificates in this connection?

```
 XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.
                                builder()
                                .setHost("jabber.blah.im")
                                .setPort(5222)
                                .setXmppDomain("blah.im")
                                .setUsernameAndPassword(username, password)
                                .setSendPresence(true)
                                .setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.required)
                                .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                                .build();

 XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
 connection.connect();
 connection.login();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used below code to config SSL/TLC certificates for connection.

```
  try {
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setDebuggerEnabled(XMPP_DEBUG_MODE)
                .setXmppDomain(JidCreate.from(SERVICE_NAME).asDomainBareJid())
                .setHost(SERVER_NAME)
                .setPort(5222)
                .setSendPresence(true)
                .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);

        KeyStore keyStore = configKeyStore(builder);

        configSSLContext(builder, keyStore);

        config = builder.build();

    } catch (KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | XmppStringprepException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

//configKey Store

```
  private KeyStore configKeyStore(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder) throws KeyStoreException {
    KeyStore keyStore;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        builder.setKeystorePath(null);
        builder.setKeystoreType("AndroidCAStore");
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
    } else {
        builder.setKeystoreType("BKS");
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

        String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
        if (path == null)
            path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc"
                    + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
                    + "cacerts.bks";
        builder.setKeystorePath(path);
    }
    return keyStore;
}
```

//config ssl contex

```
  private void configSSLContext(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder, KeyStore keyStore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
            .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

    builder.setCustomSSLContext(sslContext);
}
```

Comment: why are you using `setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);`